# Data mutate in R

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2

I have a data frame like this:

```
Var1 Var2 value
x5   x1   2
x6   x1   6
x1   x2   2
x5   x2   2
x6   x2   4
x7   x2   3
```

And I'd like to reshape/aggregate/summarise it according to corresponding `Var2` with minimum values of each pairs of `Var1`, just like that:

```
Var3 Var4 minvalue
x5   x6   2
x1   x5   2
x1   x6   2
x1   x7   2
x5   x6   2
x5   x7   2
x6   x7   3
```

If you combine `Var1` values by corresponding `Var2` values select minimum value. E.g `x1` as `Var2` is connects `x5` and `x6` as `Var1` and value is min(x5,x6)=2

Any idea?

Comment: How are the two datasets related? This question needs clarifying as it is impossible to know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I think this is what you needed `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df1[-2], df1$Var2), function(x) {x1 <- combn(x$Var1, 2, FUN = list); data.frame(do.call(rbind, x1),minvalue = sapply(x1, function(y) min(x$value[x$Var1 %in% y]))) }))`

Comment: Or use `data.table` i.e. `setDT(df1)[, {x1 <- combn(Var1, 2, FUN = list); data.frame(do.call(rbind, x1), minvalue = sapply(x1, function(y) min(value[Var1 %in% y])), stringsAsFactors= FALSE)}, Var2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description, we need to do a groupby `combn` to get the `min` 'value' of the 'pairs'.  A `base R` option would be to `split` by the 'Var2' and then do the `combn` on 'Var1', get the `min` of 'value' by subsetting the corresponding values for each 'Var1'

```
res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df1[-2], df1$Var2), function(x) {
       x1 <- combn(x$Var1, 2, FUN = list)
      data.frame(do.call(rbind, x1),minvalue = sapply(x1, function(y) 
                 min(x$value[x$Var1 %in% y]))) }))
row.names(res) <- NULL
res
#  X1 X2 minvalue
#1 x5 x6        2
#2 x1 x5        2
#3 x1 x6        2
#4 x1 x7        2
#5 x5 x6        2
#6 x5 x7        2
#7 x6 x7        3
```

---

Or we can use `data.table`, grouped by 'Var2', do the `combn` as earlier

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, {
         x1 <- combn(Var1, 2, FUN = list)
         data.frame(do.call(rbind, x1), 
              minvalue = sapply(x1, function(y) min(value[Var1 %in% y])),
             stringsAsFactors= FALSE)
           }, by = Var2]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Var1 = c("x5", "x6", "x1", "x5", "x6", "x7"), 
Var2 = c("x1", "x1", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2"), value = c(2L, 
6L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L)), .Names = c("Var1", "Var2", "value"),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thank's @akrun, great solutions. I tested both of them on a bigger dataset and working well. Thank's again.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative solution using `data.table's` *non-equi join*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, rn := .I][
  df1, on = .(Var2, rn < rn), nomatch = 0L, allow = TRUE,
  .(Var3 = Var1, Var4 = i.Var1, minvalue = pmin(value, i.value))]
```

> ```
>    Var3 Var4 minvalue
> 1:   x5   x6        2
> 2:   x1   x5        2
> 3:   x1   x6        2
> 4:   x5   x6        2
> 5:   x1   x7        2
> 6:   x5   x7        2
> 7:   x6   x7        3
> ```

The join on `Var2` is equivalent to grouping by `Var2` while the join condition `rn < rn` on the row number replaces `combn()`.

I wonder how this code compares to [akrun's solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47055665/3817004) in terms of speed if applied to a bigger data set.